# I’m trying to join my friend on Minecraft but it’s giving me an issue

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m trying to join her world and we have joined escort her before in the same world, but sometimes when I try to play with her it says that I have no friends playing Minecraft but then when I go on the Xbox app it says she is on Minecraft and i don’t get her invites. It’s really weird. This is pocket edition [image]

Comment: Just for clarification: You play Pocket Edition and your friend is playing the Xbox edition?

Comment: Are you sure you're not on Bedrock Edition? PE is mobile.